# Why wouldn't this recursive constructor cause compile time error?

Tags: java, recursion, constructor, scjp

Consider following code

```
class ConstructorDemo2{
    ConstructorDemo2(){
        this(1);
    }
    ConstructorDemo2(int i){
        this();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ConstructorDemo2();
    }
}
```

Kathy Sierra's SCJP6 book says on page 144 that 
a code like this might go undetected and cause StackOverflowError. But at the same time, we know subclass constructor ALWAYS has to call the superclass constructor using `super()` [default provided by compiler]
but in the following code sample, both constructors are invoking `this()` (calling each other) .
It does show the error `error: recursive constructor invocation` in my OpenJDK compiler, but Kathy Sierra's book says such a code might go undetected by compiler and will throw a exception at runtime.

So if such a code sample is shown to me in SCJP/OCJP exam and asked whether it will compile, what what would be the answer ? seems a bit ambiguous

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt, read what the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) has to say :

> 8.8.7. Constructor Body
>
> ...
>
> It is a compile-time error for a constructor to directly or indirectly
>   invoke itself through a series of one or more explicit constructor
>   invocations involving this.

Therefore, your code shouldn't pass compilation. If some compiler doesn't detect this error, it doesn't comply with the Java language specification.

Comment: yes its ok but the SCJP book confused me. Makes you wonder what else the authors got wrong !

Comment: @Sarabjeet I would trust the JLS over any book, especially when it makes such a clear statement on this issue.

Comment: its all and good, but its not feasible to study from such a lengthy manual specification , is it ? sometimes u just want as much material to ace the exam. Rest nuances you learn as you're working with the language

Comment: @Sarabjeet You are *obliged* to take what it says in the JLS over any other source whatsoever other than the JVM Specification. These are the only normative references. If anything else contradicts it, it's wrong.

Comment: The material in the disputed book may have originated prior to JDK 1.4.1 - that is, when javac wasn't able to detect this and a class could have unusable constructors.

Comment: @JirkaHanika That's possible. I didn't consider checking older versions of the JLS.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would never pass compilation. It should give you compile time error-  "*recursive constructor invocation*"

Comment: Agree ! But Kathy Sierra's book seem to have made this mistake (no disrespect meant to experience authors) , but even on a previous page 109 they said a method like `void eat() throws IOException` would cause error if it is overriding `void eat() throws Exception` but it is infact legal because `IOException` is subclass of `Exception` 
and therefore the overriding method can throw a subclass of the exception thrown by the overriden method. Makes me wonder what else errors they made in book. Again no disrespect intended to august authors.